# Error casting an object when using the ForeignKey attribute

Tags: c#, model, casting, asp.net-mvc-5, foreign-key-relationship

I am coding a C# MVC5 Internet Application, and have a question in regards to setting the foreign key reference in one of my objects.

I have a `House` object that has a `List<Room>`. I am wanting to add the foreign key reference in the `Room` object that refers to the `House` that the `Room` is a part of.

Here is my code:

```
public class House
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Room> rooms { get; set; }

    public House()
    {
        rooms = new List<Room>();
    }
}

public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int roomNumber { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public House house { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Create action result for creating a `House`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include="Id,name")] House house)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.houses.Add(house);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.rooms, "Id", "Id", house.Id);
    return View(house);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestDeleteForeignKeyReferences.Models.Room]' to type 'TestDeleteForeignKeyReferences.Models.Room'.
```

At the following line of code:

```
db.houses.Add(house);
```

If I do not have the following line of code in the `Room` object, no error occurs:

```
[ForeignKey("Id")]
```

Have I not coded the foreign key reference correctly? What do I need to do to get this code working?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I have coded my classes to be what you have coded in your answer, now when I am trying to create a new Room controller, I am getting the following error:

http://www.canninginc.co.nz/ForumPost/House_Room_Controller_Error.png

Answer (score 0):

Your models should be (you've got an incorrect usage of the foreign key attribute and you're missing "virtual" directive in the "house" property):

```
public class House
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> rooms { get; set; }

    public House()
    {
        rooms = new List<Room>();
    }
}

public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int roomNumber { get; set; }
    public int HouseId {get; set; }
    public virtual House house { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you actually need the [ForeignKey] attribute (Entity Framework usually just figures it out).  Try removing that attribute.

Comment: Could you please provide the code for your class that inherits DbContext?

Comment: I made another code change; I use ICollection instead of List (List implements ICollection).  I'm not sure if this will help, but that how I've always done one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.